# SQL total for each row combination

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Are there any types of aggregate functions that could help calculate the following?

If I have the following data, I want the sum total for each duplicated row.

```
   date    |  country     | color | measure |  left | position 
---------------------------------------------------------------
2020-02-01  united states  red        33       5.3      none  
2020-02-01  united states  red        33       5.3      none  
2020-02-01  united states  red        33       5.3      none  
2020-02-03  vietnam        green      44       9.2      none  
2020-02-01  united states  red        33       5.3      none  
2020-02-01  united states  red        33       5.3      none  
2020-02-03  vietnam        green      44       9.2      none  
2020-02-01  canada         yellow     20       3.1      none  
2020-02-06  mexico         orange     2        9.0      miss
2020-02-06  mexico         red        1        3.0      none
```

The output would provide `total` number each row occurs:

```
   date    |  country     | color | measure |  left | position | total
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-02-01  united states  red        33       5.3      none      5
2020-02-03  vietnam        green      44       9.2      none      2
2020-02-01  canada         yellow     20       3.1      none      1
2020-02-06  mexico         orange     2        9.0      miss      1
2020-02-06  mexico         red        1        3.0      none      1
```

Comment: Search for "count group by tutorial". This appears to be a trivial query.

Comment: Looks like a `count(*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not good old `group by` and `count`?

```
  select date,
         country,
         color,
         measure,
         left,
         position,
         count(1) as total      
    from MyTable
group by date,
         country,
         color,
         measure,
         left,
         position
```